# sum duplicate row with condition using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe who looks like this:

```
  Name  rent  sale
0    A   180     2
1    B     1     4
2    M    12     1
3    O    10     1
4    A   180     5
5    M     2    19
```

that i want to make condition that if i have a **duplicate row** and a **duplicate value in column field** => Example :

- **duplicate row A** have *duplicate value* ***180 in rent column***
  I keep only one (without making the sum)
- Or make **the sum** => Example **duplicate row A** with *different values* ***2 & 5 in Sale column*** and **duplicate row M** with different **values in rent & sales columns**

Expected output:

```
  Name  rent  sale
0    A   180     7
1    B     1     4
2    M    14     20
3    O    10     1
```

I tried this code but it's not workin as i want

```
import pandas as pd 
    
df=pd.DataFrame({'Name':['A','B','M','O','A','M'],
                 'rent':[180,1,12,10,180,2],
                 'sale':[2,4,1,1,5,19]})
df2 = df.drop_duplicates().groupby('Name',sort=False,as_index=False).agg(Name=('Name','first'),
                                                                            rent=('rent', 'sum'),
                                                                            sale=('sale','sum'))
    
print(df2)
```

I got this output

```
  Name  rent  sale
0    A   360     7
1    B     1     4
2    M    14    20
3    O    10     1
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Can try summing only the [`unique`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.unique.html) values per group:

```
def sum_unique(s):
    return s.unique().sum()


df2 = df.groupby('Name', sort=False, as_index=False).agg(
    Name=('Name', 'first'),
    rent=('rent', sum_unique),
    sale=('sale', sum_unique)
)
```

`df2`:

```
  Name  rent  sale
0    A   180     7
1    B     1     4
2    M    14    20
3    O    10     1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can first groupby by `Name` **and** `rent`, and then just by `Name`:

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Name', 'rent'], as_index=False).sum().groupby('Name', as_index=False).sum()
```